# "single-row subquery returns more than one row" in SQL Developer Query Result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a complex SQL statement with individual fields and few complex CASE statements that sum up few values to come up with a score. When I try to export the output of this SQL, I am running into following error message:

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

I understand that this is something that comes up in SUBQuery scenario that retunrs > 1 value but I am uanble to understand why this happens when exporting the data.

Here is the sample SQL statement:

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a subquery here, can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes,..that's what the point is, I don't have a sub query. Query runs fine yielding rows but when I try to export the output as csv, the above problem occurs

Comment: I cant see any error on that query, I sugest you start removing columns to make it simple until you find the error.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you are exporting to csv?

Comment: are you using a view?

Comment: Does the query run fine when you view all of the results or just the first page (e.g. in SQL Developer's query result window, can you scroll right to the bottom without getting the error)? Are you exporting from the query results window or some other way? And you said there's no subquery but you mostly seem to be talking about the select list - there is no subquery in the join conditions/where clause either?

Comment: I cannot scroll the entire resultset, I can only see the first page of the output @AlexPoole

Comment: SQL Developer gives you an option to export output of a view into csv. I am not using view but I tried to embed the query into an inline view, for eg, with view as (select query) select * from view but that did not help either.                                                                After eliminating some fields, realized that case statement that sums up the score is causing the error message. Query would return entire result set without the score field.

Comment: Why can't you scroll - because it errors if you try then too? Not sure what you mean about 'option to export output of a view'; it lets you export any result set if you right-click on the results in the query output window, is that what you mean? The case expression you've shown can't throw that error. (Unless you've uncovered/hit a really weird bug). Are you sure your real code isn't actually doing `...coln,(SELECT case ... <from somewhere>)` ? You really need to show your full query, and clarify if you can retrieve the entire result set - i.e. if it's actually anything to do with export.

Comment: "*When I try to export the output of this SQL, I am running into following error message*" - does that mean the error does not appear when you just display the (entire) result? Does it work with SQL\*Plus?

Comment: from your case statement... are A, B & C columns?

Answer (score 0):

One of my inner queries is causing this bug. I overlooked it since the SQL Developer returned rows on the first run. Fixing that join helped me solve the problem